# Is there any mention from our sages of blessed memory of Alexander The Great building a big metal wall in Central Asia to keep Gog and Magog at bay?

Tags: history, rabbis, messiah

Is there anything that our Sages, of blessed memory, say about Alexander the Great building a big metal wall in Central Asia to prevent Gog and Magog from invading the greater part of the world?  The Quran talks about this so I wondered if they based it on anything from our tradition.

Comment: You are quoting the Koran which is extremely late for Alexander. The wall you are discussing is a historical fact and is found in pre-Islamic, Persian historical records. It has been many years, but if memory serves, I think the Kaplan translation of Me'Am Lo'Ez had something mentioning it with footnotes giving sources.

Comment: I believe it pointed to Midrash Rabbah and the commentary Yafeh To'ar. This wall was located in what is modern Afghanistan. This was one of the historical pointers to why the war in Afghanistan is associated with the war of Gog u'Magog.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that the Sages might have said anything about such a story?

Comment: Who paid for the wall?

Comment: This is not mentioned in the midrashim, but the "Gates of Alexander" are already mentioned by the works of Josephus if you consider it a Jewish source. See this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gates_of_Alexander

Comment: Ultimately “paid for itself”.

Comment: @GershonGold Mexico?

Comment: @ezra השותפין שרצו לעשות מחיצה בחצר בונין את הכותל באמצע

Comment: @DonielF I love how serious you are

Answer (score 1):

This is written about explicitly by Rabbi Yehudah Teichtal in the names of [Rabbi Avraham Saba](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Saba), the author of Sefer Tzror HaMor, and Rabbi Yosef Kimchi in his commentary on the later Prophets.

According to Rabbi Teichtal's explanation, this concept relates to the beginning of the third and final part of the war of Gog u'Magog during the 'Days of Moshiach'.

It connects the building of an iron wall by Alexander the Great which was intended to keep the nation associated with Gog u'Magog trapped in 'the mountains' with their later release by HaShem to start this final conflict. The beginning of this conflict is indicated by the destruction of an iron building which it describes as 'the mountains and heights will all fall to the earth'.

This describes what precipitated the war in Afghanistan, namely the destruction of the World Trade Center towers on September 11, 2001. This event is also referenced in the [Zohar, parshat Balak 212b, Chapter 402](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14246&st=&pgnum=667).

As I mentioned on comments to your question, I believe this also is discussed in Me'Am Lo'ez by Rabbi Yakov Culi who is bringing a citation from the commentary Yefeh To'ar on Midrash Rabbah.

[Mishnah Sachir al HaTorah by Rabbi Yissachar S. Teichtal, pp. 186-187](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53714&st=&pgnum=230)

> וברוב גאונך תהרס קמיך [שמות טו, ז]
>   ארשום מה שמצאתי בסה״ק צרור המור להקדוש ר׳ אברהם סבע חמיו זקנו של רבינו הב״י בפ׳ בשלח [ד״ה ובזוהר כתבו] בפירוש דברי הזוהר על פסוק [טו, ז] וברוב גאונן מהמס קמין אלו גוג ומגוג שיקומו נגד הקב״ה, דכתיב [תהלים ב, א] למה רגשו גוים הם גוג ומגוג דכתיב על ה׳ ומשיחו. וביאר הוא ז״ל **דפירשו תהרוס קמיך בגוג ומגוג שהוא הריסת בנין**, על פי מה שראה **בפירוש של ר׳ יוסף קמחי על נביאים אחרונים** שראה כתוב בספר אחד **כי אלכסנדר מוקדון הסגיר לגוג ומגוג בהרים גדולים וגבוהים שאין להם מוצא אלא ממקום אחד, ובאותו מקום בנה בנין חזק מחומת ברזל שלא יכלו לצאת**, **ובאותה חומה עשה** בחכמה גדולה אנשים **מברזל** שהם מכים תמיד בחומה במיני פטישים וקרדומות בענין שיבינו האנשים שמבפנים שלעולם **בונין אותו** **ומחזיקים אותו באופן שלא יצאו משם לעולם**, **ולפי שזה הבנין לא יהרס ולא יפתח עד שיבא אותו יום הגדול והנורא שירצה השם שיצאו** **משם, דכתיב [יחזקאל לח, יח] ״ביום בא גוג על אדמת ישראל״, לפי שאז ירצה השם לקדש שמו ולהודיעו לעיני הגוים, שנאמר [שם לח, כג] ״והתגדלתי והתקדשתי ונודעתי לעיני גוים רבים״, ולפי שאז יהרוס השי״ת אותו בנין כדי שיצאו**, אמר הקדוש רשב״י וברוב גאונך תהרוס קמיך אלו גוג ומגוג, ולזה תמצא שרמז יחזקאל [שם לח,  ג-ה] באומרו במפלת גוג ומגוג ״והוצאתי אותך ואת כל חילך״, כי זאת ההוצאה היא יציאת אותם הרים. וכן אמר [ שם טו] ״ובאת ממקומך מירכתי צפון״. ואמר בפרשת ביום בא גוג ונהרסו ההרים ונפלו המדרגות וכל הומה לארץ תפול, שזה רמז על ההומה שאמרנו שבנה אלכסנדר מקרון ואז התגדלתי והתקדשתי. וכל זה רמוז באומרו תהרוס קמיך לעתיד.

Comment: Could you please translate (at least the keyaspects) the Zohar source? I doubt that it's a reference to the world trade center.

Comment: @Anonymous Lol, I doubt that too; it’s OP’s allusion.

Comment: Yakkov you have merely demonstrated that some Jewish sources have been influenced by this old tradition and even cited it in their works, however it still doesn't make it a chazalic tradition. The earliest Jewish source for this tradition I believe is Josephus. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gates_of_Alexander

Comment: @Bach It's not Josephus. The source you are referencing is Yosiphun. They are different. And yes, the subject also appears there although only in it's historical context. What comes to us via Radak is how Chazal understood that phenomenon. And that is what is quoted later by Rabbi Saba and later yet by Rabbi Teichtal, the same Rabbi Teichtal who also authored 'Eim HaBanim Sameicha'.

Comment: @YaacovDeane you are mistaken. The Radak does not in any way represent the view of chazal, he is citing an independent source which can be Josephus or maybe even of Greek or Islamic origin. I reiterate: The radak does not prove that chazal in any way knew of this tradition, or endorsed it.

Comment: I would also like to know how Josephus and Yosiphun are different.